# Replacement for ScopeVoter in oauth2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Working on porting older oauth2 code to the new integrated spring security oauth2.

Is there any replacement for org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter?